# Libgdx - scrolling shop

Tags: android, libgdx

Making a shop (about 50 objects in it that can be bought), so I need a scrollable area as not everything can go on on it.

This is the part when you are holding and sliding your finger.

```
public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
    float scaleY = viewport.getWorldHeight() / (float)viewport.getScreenHeight();
    camera.translate((int) 0, (int) (deltaY * scaleY));

    return true;
}
```

The moment you release the finger this fires up.

```
public boolean fling(float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
    float scaleY = viewport.getWorldHeight() / (float)viewport.getScreenHeight();
    translation = scaleY * velocityY;
    return false;
}
```

The logic to move the camera from fling is this:

```
if (translation != 0) {
        camera.translate(0, translation * delta);

        if (translation >= 0) {
            up = true;
            translation -= increasing * delta;
        } else {
            up = false;
            translation += increasing * delta;
        }
        if (translation <= 0 && up) {
            translation = 0;
        } else if (translation >= 0 && !up) {
            translation = 0;
        }
        increasing += 10000*delta;
    }
```

So I have been playing around with these a little but cannot get a perfect scrolling speed. Has anybody done this before and knows the perfect starting speed ('translation') and stopping speed ('increasing')?

Comment: is there any reason why you not using scene2d? There is scrollPane ready to use for purposes like this

Comment: oh really? never used scene2d... I can't find any code examples for that